# Calculate share of value per date and country and handle zero values separately

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49c11efd4e68b7fda3209ee2949c8483)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    channel VARCHAR,
    sales DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, country, channel, sales)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_01', '500'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_03', '200'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_01', '900'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_02', '800'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_01', '100'),

('2020-03-20', 'DE', 'channel_01', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_01', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_02', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_03', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'NL', 'channel_01', '0'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '700'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '500'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_01', '850'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_02', '250'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_03', '300');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date  |  country  |  share_per_day_per_country |        details of share calculation
------------|-----------|----------------------------|--------------------------------------------
2020-02-08  |     DE    |           0.379            |  = (500+400+200) / (500+400+200+900+800+100)
2020-02-08  |     FR    |           0.586            |  = (900+800)     / (500+400+200+900+800+100)
2020-02-08  |     NL    |           0.034            |  = (100)         / (500+400+200+900+800+100)
------------|-----------|----------------------------|--------------------------------------------
2020-03-20  |     DE    |           0.333            |  = equal split in case of 0 sales
2020-03-20  |     FR    |           0.333            |  = equal split in case of 0 sales
2020-03-20  |     NL    |           0.333            |  = equal split in case of 0 sales
------------|-----------|----------------------------|--------------------------------------------
2020-04-15  |     DE    |           0.269            |  = (700)         / (700+500+850+250+300)
2020-04-15  |     FR    |           0.192            |  = (500)         / (700+500+850+250+300)
2020-04-15  |     NL    |           0.538            |  = (850+250+300) / (700+500+850+250+300)
```

---

In the expected result I want to

1. calculate the **share of the sales per country per day**
2. in case there is a day with **no sales** the share should be **divided equaly** to the number of countries.

---

In order to achieve this so far I have developed this query:

```
SELECT
t1.event_date,
t1.country,
t1.sales,
t1.total_sales_per_country,
t1.total_sales_per_day,

(CASE WHEN SUM(t1.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.event_date) = 0 THEN 
100/(COUNT(t1.country) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.event_date))/100::decimal
ELSE t1.total_sales_per_country / t1.total_sales_per_day END) AS share_per_day_per_country
  
FROM

  (SELECT
  s.event_date,
  s.country,
  s.sales,
  SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date) AS total_sales_per_day,
  SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date, s.country) AS total_sales_per_country
  FROM sales s
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  ORDER BY 1,2) t1
  
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2
```

This query almost gives me the correct result. 
However, instead of listing each `event_date` **only one time** it lists them multiple times.

I have tried a few ways (e.g. `DSTINCT pl.event_date`) to fix this issue but none of them worked.

How do I have to modify the query to get the entire expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove t1.sales and t1.total_sales_per_country from the select list. Now use distinct instead of group by.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales (
>     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>     event_date DATE,
>     country VARCHAR,
>     channel VARCHAR,
>     sales DECIMAL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sales
> (event_date, country, channel, sales)
> VALUES 
> ('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_01', '500'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_02', '400'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_03', '200'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_01', '900'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_02', '800'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_01', '100'),
>
> ('2020-03-20', 'DE', 'channel_01', '0'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_01', '0'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_02', '0'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'FR', 'channel_03', '0'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'NL', 'channel_01', '0'),
>
> ('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '700'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '500'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_01', '850'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_02', '250'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_03', '300');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT
> distinct t1.event_date,
> t1.country,
> t1.total_sales_per_day,
>
> (CASE WHEN SUM(t1.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.event_date) = 0 THEN 
> 100/(COUNT(t1.country) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.event_date))/100::decimal
> ELSE t1.total_sales_per_country / t1.total_sales_per_day END) AS share_per_day_per_country
>   
> FROM
>   (SELECT
>   s.event_date,
>   s.country,
>   s.sales,
>   SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date) AS total_sales_per_day,
>   SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date, s.country) AS total_sales_per_country
>   FROM sales s
>   GROUP BY 1,2,3
>   ORDER BY 1,2) t1
>   ORDER BY 1,2
> ```

**Output:**

> | event_date | country | total_sales_per_day | share_per_day_per_country |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-02-08 | DE | 2900 | 0.37931034482758620690 |
> | 2020-02-08 | FR | 2900 | 0.58620689655172413793 |
> | 2020-02-08 | NL | 2900 | 0.03448275862068965517 |
> | 2020-03-20 | DE | 0 | 0.33000000000000000000 |
> | 2020-03-20 | FR | 0 | 0.33000000000000000000 |
> | 2020-03-20 | NL | 0 | 0.33000000000000000000 |
> | 2020-04-15 | DE | 2600 | 0.26923076923076923077 |
> | 2020-04-15 | FR | 2600 | 0.19230769230769230769 |
> | 2020-04-15 | NL | 2600 | 0.53846153846153846154 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=047cdd8fe4c1875ef8c546f3c47b830c)*